# Python Selenium driver.get opens blank url

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Selenium isn't opening any links just opens to the google home page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe')
        
driver.get("https://kissmanga.in/kissmanga/eternal-kingdom/chapter-13/");
        
#driver.maximize_window()
#scroll down pixel by pixel
#driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,1000)","")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `executable_path` looks like you are sending `browser` path, but not `driver path.`

You can download [Chrome driver from here](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/)

and then place that `.exe` file to any folder and use it like this :-

```
driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='full path of driver should be given here')
```

Comment: Beat me up to it :)

Answer (score 1):

Your driver path should redirect to the chrome driver executable.
You can download latest version from here:

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=93.0.4577.15/

Comment: hehe, you were fast too.